# Renaming label names in AucTex to recover ordered sequence

Tags: auctex, reftex

By rearranging (copy-and-pasting) math environments the automatically RefTeX generated label numbers

```
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:5}
    ...
\end{align}

texttexttext...

\begin{align}
  \label{eq:3}
   ...
\end{align}
```

become shuffled which makes the referencing to individual equations difficult.

How it is possible to rename the label names so that an increasing order is recovered?

Comment: Much of the point of the `\label / \ref` system is that you can use labels that are meaningful to you, rather than being a random number, and then LaTeX sorts out the numbering for you.  I would recommend using e.g. a label such as `eq:Einstein` for the Einstein equation, instead of numbered labels.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Reftex allows you to insert labels with context information (using `C-c C-)` ), which, together with automatic numbering, makes the key of the label more or less useless.

Comment: @T.Verron I use that mechanism of `reftex` all the time, but find itvery helpful to have keys that have meaningful names when working with my source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like how you asked "how is it possible to..." instead of "is it possible to...". Because of course it is possible, `reftex` being awesome and OCD-friendly. `:)`

> `reftex-renumber-simple-labels` is an interactive autoloaded Lisp
>   function.
>
> Renumber all simple labels in the document to make them sequentially.

So... `M-x reftex-renumber-simple-labels RET y` and you are done. It should even work across files. Note that you will get an error if the labels are already ordered, though.